# How can I use header() function to redirect to index if login is successful?

Tags: php, header

I have created a website and am implementing login functionality. I have created separate php file for main menu and am including it as required. When I try to login it says header has already been sent. I am new to php and wanted to implement master page and child pages but session seeems to create a problem.

Tried storing Request_URI in session and redirect using header for index to login if not logged in and from login to index on successfull login.

index page

Login page

```
<?php include('includes/session/mysession.php') ?>
<?php include('includes/navigation/navigation.php') ?>
<?php include('DbConnections/config.php') ?>

<section id="login-page-wrap" class="section-padding">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-8 m-auto">
            <div class="login-page-content">


                <?php

                if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
                    $uname = $_POST['username'];
                    $pwd = $_POST['password'];
                    if (empty($uname) || empty($pwd)) {
                        $output = "Please enter all fields.";
                        echo 'output : ' . $output;
                    } else {

                        $uname = $mysqli->real_escape_string($uname);
                        $pwd = $mysqli->real_escape_string($pwd);

                        echo $uname;
                        echo $pwd;

                        $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM users 
                                                WHERE username = '$uname' 
                                                AND password = md5('$pwd')");

                        echo 'query done';
                        if ($query->num_rows == 0) {
                            $output = "Invalid username/password";
                            // echo $output;
                        } else {
                            echo 'Success';
                            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
                            $_SESSION['user'] = $uname;

                            $output = "WELCOME " . $_SESSION['user'];
                            // On successful login
                            $redirect = $_SESSION['redirect_to'];
                            // unset the session var
                            unset($_SESSION['redirect_to']);
                            header("Location: $redirect");
                            exit();
                            // header('location: index.php');
                            // echo $output;
                        }
                    }
                }
                //echo 'output : ' . $output;
                ?>
                <?php
                if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {  ?>
                    <div class="login-form">
                        <h3>Welcome !</h3>
                        <form method="POST">
                            <div class="username">
                                <input name="username" type="text" placeholder="Email or Username">
                            </div>
                            <div class="password">
                                <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                            <div class="log-btn">
                                <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Log In</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                <?php
                } else {
                    echo 'Done.';
                }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

config.php

```
<?php
/* Database credentials. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
//pass variables for values
$dbserver = 'localhost';
$dbusername = 'root';
$dbpassword = '';
$dbname = 'cs';
define('DB_SERVER', $dbserver);
define('DB_USERNAME', $dbusername);
define('DB_PASSWORD', $dbpassword);
define('DB_NAME', $dbname);

/* Attempt to connect to MySQL database */
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

// Check connection
if ($mysqli === false) {
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
?>
```

mysession.php

```
<?php session_start();?>
```

mainmenu.php

````
<?php
$HomeActive = '';
$ServiceActive = '';
$CarsActive = '';
$AboutActive = '';
$BlogActive = '';
$PagesActive = '';
$ContactsActive = '';
?>
<div class="col-lg-8 d-none d-xl-block">
    <nav class="mainmenu alignright">
        <ul>
            <li class="<?php echo $HomeActive; ?>"><a href="#">Home</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.php">Home 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index2.php">Home 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index3.php">Home 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="<?php echo $AboutActive; ?>"><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
            <li class="<?php echo $ServiceActive; ?>"><a href="services.php">services</a></li>
            <li class="<?php echo $CarsActive; ?>"><a href="#">Cars</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="car-left-sidebar.php">Car Left Sidebar</a></li>
                    <li><a href="car-right-sidebar.php">Car Right Sidebar</a></li>
                    <li><a href="car-without-sidebar.php">Car Without Sidebar</a></li>
                    <li><a href="car-details.php">Car Details</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="<?php echo $PagesActive; ?>"><a href="index.php">Pages</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="package.php">Pricing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="driver.php">Driver</a></li>
                    <li><a href="faq.php">FAQ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="gallery.php">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="help-desk.php">Help Desk</a></li>
                    <li><a href="login.php">Log In</a></li>
                    <li><a href="register.php">Register</a></li>
                    <li><a href="404.php">404</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="<?php echo $BlogActive; ?>"><a href="#">Blog</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="article.php">Blog Page</a></li>
                    <li><a href="article-details.php">Blog Details</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="<?php echo $ContactsActive; ?>"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>```
````

navigation.php

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html cla s s="no-js" la n g="zx x">

    <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!--=== Favicon ===-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

    <title>Cardoor - Car Rental HTML Template</title>

    <!--=== Bootstrap CSS ===-->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--=== Slicknav CSS ===-->
    <link href="assets/css/plugins/slicknav.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--=== Magnific Popup CSS ===-->
    <link href="assets/css/plugins/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--=== Owl Carousel CSS ===-->
    <link href="assets/css/plugins/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--=== Gijgo CSS ===-->
    <link href="assets/css/plugins/gijgo.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--=== FontAwesome CSS ===-->
    <link href="assets/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--=== Theme Reset CSS ===-->
    <link href="assets/css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--=== Main Style CSS ===-->
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--=== Responsive CSS ===-->
    <link href="assets/css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="//oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body class="loader-active">

    <!--== Preloader Area Start ==-->
    <!-- <div class="preloader">
        <div class="preloader-spinner">
            <div class="loader-content">
                <img src="assets/img/preloader.gif" alt="JSOFT">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> -->
    <!--== Preloader Area End ==-->

    <!--== Header Area Start ==-->
    <header id="header-area" class="fixed-top">
        <!--== Header Top Start ==-->
        <div id="header-top" class="d-none d-xl-block">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <!--== Single HeaderTop Start ==-->
                    <div class="col-lg-3 text-left">
                        <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> 802/2, Mirpur, Dhaka
                    </div>
                    <!--== Single HeaderTop End ==-->

                    <!--== Single HeaderTop Start ==-->
                    <div class="col-lg-3 text-center">
                        <i class="fa fa-mobile"></i> +1 800 345 678
                    </div>
                    <!--== Single HeaderTop End ==-->

                    <!--== Single HeaderTop Start ==-->
                    <div class="col-lg-3 text-center">
                        <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Mon-Fri 09.00 - 17.00
                    </div>
                    <!--== Single HeaderTop End ==-->

                    <!--== Social Icons Start ==-->
                    <div class="col-lg-3 text-right">
                        <div class="header-social-icons">
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-behance"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--== Social Icons End ==-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--== Header Top End ==-->

        <!--== Header Bottom Start ==-->
        <div id="header-bottom">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <!--== Logo Start ==-->
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <a href="index.php" class="logo">
                            <img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="JSOFT">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <!--== Logo End ==-->

                    <!--== Main Menu Start ==-->
                    <?php include('includes/navigation/mainmenu.php') ?>

                    <!--== Main Menu End ==-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--== Header Bottom End ==-->
    </header>
    <!--== Header Area End ==-->```
````

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text or using MD5/SHA1!** Only store password hashes. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I really hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) library to get the same functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You echoed, before the redirect header, that's why you're getting that message. What you want to achieve looks like a client side job. Try replacing the php redirect with js.

Replace this:

```
header("Location: $redirect");
```

with this

```
echo "<script>window.location = '$redirect';</script>";
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but is it the proper way and is my approach right?

Comment: You can do it by sending the PHP header, but you have to remove all echoes and HTML before the call. You also need to remove any includes for files with HTML (e.g navigation.php).